# File.Move is adding a padlock to file image

Tags: c#

I'm making a bit of code in Visual Studio to sort my music files (`.m4a`).
I have a listbox with a list of files on my desktop.
My code loops through each file.
Example files:

- [Eminem] Not alone.m4a
- [Imagine Dragons] Radioactive.m4a
- [Dragon Force] Through Fire and Flames.m4a

```
if (file.Contains(".m4a"))
{
    stat_sorted_audio++;
    var artist = file.Split(new char[] { '[', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(@folder_music + artist[0] + "\\");
    if (!exists)
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@folder_music + artist[0] + "\\");
    }
    string s_file = file.Replace("[" + artist[0] + "]", "");
    string s_target = folder_music + artist[0] + "\\";
    string s_source = folder_desktop + file;
    label2.Text = s_file + "\n" + s_target + "\n" + s_source;
    moveFile(s_source, s_target, s_file, ".m4a");
}
```

And the function to move files:

```
public void moveFile(string source, string target, string file)
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(target+file))
    {
        System.IO.File.Move(@source, @target + file);
    }
}
```

This works fine and I end up with the files in the correct folder, but once the files have moved a padlock is appearing next to the icon, I don't want this.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: [Wait, so does moving a file recalculate inherited permissions or doesn't it?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/09/24/10451467.aspx)

Comment: Padlock usually indicates that the `Users` group don't have access to the file. It could be that they previously inherited permissions from the source folder and the new folder you create have different permissions

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I checked the permissions in the properties. I still have full access to it. And I've tried creating new folders, Same problem occurs. The weird thing is it doesn't happen with moving PNG, JPG or GIF files.

Comment: @InuKenshi Are you by any chance member of the local `Administrators` group on the machine? If so you'll have access to it even though `Users` doesn't grant it

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Yes. I am. Even though I can access the file, I still don't like it having the padlock icon next to it. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: Aside: use [`Path.GetExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `file.Contains`. What if the file is called `"hello.m4a.mp3"`? The extension in that case is `.mp3` but it does contain `.m4a`.

Comment: Didn't know that existed, Thanks.

Comment: @InuKenshi you'll want to look at [`File.GetAccessControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`File.SetAccessControl()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, I'll look into that, Thanks.